# I get this error when trying to install, purge, etc

Tags: apt, java, dpkg, oracle

```
Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:
 oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
       Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 oracle-java8-set-default
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of downloaded `jdk-8u***-linux-x64.tar.gz` did not pass `SHA256` checksum, installer can't do next process. Dependency problem.

Remove `oracle-jdk8-installer` cache.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-*
```

Install again `oracle-jdk8-installer`

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default
```

Check downloading progress. `jdk-8u***-linux-x64.tar.gz` file size may be more than 150 MB.